# Include taxonomy slug in url?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, custom-taxonomy

I have the following custom post-type and custom taxonomy setup:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'system',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Systems' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'System' )
            ),
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'supports' => array('title','editor','comments'),   
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'system' ),
        )
    );
}

function news_init() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'system',
        'system',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Product Category' ),
            'sort' => true,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'args' => array( 'orderby' => 'term_order' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'products' )
        )
    );  
}
add_action( 'init', 'news_init' );
```

Is it possible to include the custom taxonomy name in the URL?

At present when I goto a custom post the URL looks like this:

> http://www.domain.com/products/(post-name)/

How can I make it look like the following?

> http://www.domain.com/(category-slug)/(post-name)/

I've tried going to that URL but it just gives a 404. I just have the standard archive template setup.

**(Please don't migrate my question to the Wordpress Stack as there isn't much action on there!)**

---

UPDATE:

I put the code below on a page just to make sure it was going to the right page and it's going to this:

> http://www.domain.com/products/(custom-taxonomy-slug)/

This gives a 404. It doesn't seem to picking up the templates (the standard ones) and I've tried adding archive-products.php as well.

```
<?php $args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'my_term' );

$terms = get_terms('system', $args);

$count = count($terms); $i=0;
if ($count > 0) {
    $term_list = '<p class="my_term-archive">';
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $i++;
        $term_list .= '<a href="' . get_term_link( $term->slug, $term->taxonomy ) . '" title="' . sprintf(__('View all post filed under %s', 'my_localization_domain'), $term->name) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
        if ($count != $i) $term_list .= ' &middot; '; else $term_list .= '</p>';
    }
    echo $term_list;
} ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I previously used [this article](http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/add-custom-taxonomy-tags-to-your-wordpress-permalinks) to achieve this. By `category-slug`, I assume you meant the  taxonomy for the custom post type you have?

Comment: I've updated my question. I came across that link and tried but still no luck. Yep the taxonomy sorry.

Comment: I've used up 2 days on it! Thanks for checking back but still no luck.